# Custom Realm on WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5

Tags: java, websphere, jaas

I'd like to know how I can develop my own Realm on WAS 8.5.5.

I found that I should implement `javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule`. But I don't know how to register this module on the server and use it on my web application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login modules are used rather, when you want to extend/customize provided login mechanisms (file, ldap). If you need completely new mechanism I'd rather suggest creating custom user registry, creating adapter for federated registry, or using bridge.

See following for more details:

- [Stand-alone custom registries](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/csec_customauth.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-8-2-33-2-1-2-0&lang=en)
- [Developing the UserRegistry interface for using custom registries](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tsec_users.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-8-2-33-2-1-2-1&lang=en)
- [Sample custom adapters for federated repositories examples](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwim_dev_vmmca.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5&lang=en)
- [User registry bridge for federated repositories](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/cwim_userregbridge.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F3-8-2-33-2-1-3-25-0&lang=en)